# ASP.NET MVC5/6 Routing based on Http Header values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's say I have a most basic controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id, string language)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Which takes in 2 parameters. However there is one requirement that the client which calls the action method should pass `id` value from URL but `language` value from http header. It means the url should be `/Home/Index/12345` and meanwhile the calling client will set a Http Header value `language : en`.

How shall I set the routing in MVC5 or MVC6 to achieve the requirement?

Please don't provide samples from Web Api.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the [`FromHeaderAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/FromHeaderAttribute.cs)? Try adding it to the language parameter as in `public ActionResult Index(string id, [FromHeader] string language)`

Comment: I never notice this attribute. But when I Google the attribute I barely see any further information other than the github page you gave me.

Comment: That "github page" is the official Microsoft repo for the new MVC framework :). But yes, documentation is scarce at the moment, hopefully they will improve it over time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an attribute [`FromHeaderAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/FromHeaderAttribute.cs). From its documentation:

> Specifies that a parameter or property should be bound using the
>   request headers.

You should be able to add it to the language parameter of your controller. By default it will look for a header with the same name than the parameter, but it also has a `name` parameter that can be used to specify a different name, for example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, [FromHeader(Name="Accept-Language")]string language)
{
    return View();
}
```

You can also have a look to the test site **ModelBindingWebSite** located in the [github MVC repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e0b8532735997c439e11fff68dd342d5af59f05f/test/WebSites/ModelBindingWebSite/Controllers/FromHeader_BlogController.cs). Check the controller named `FromHeader_BlogController`.

**PS** Looking at the source code of the [`HeaderModelBinder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/HeaderModelBinder.cs) it seems this can be used for binding strings and arrays (assuming the header has a comma separated list of values)

Comment: Great for the sample, I will give it and let you know the result.

Comment: I checked the source code of the attribute, it seems that it is difficult to extend. For example what about the http header is `Accepted-Language`, I cannot have a parameter name like it. So preferably I should be able to use `[FromHeader("Accepted-Language")]` to specify which http header value to bind from.

Comment: The attribute has a "Name" parameter, have you tried `[FromHeader(Name = "Accepted-Language")]`? In the sampes website they have a similar case `public object BindToStringParameterWithCustomName([FromHeader(Name = "tId")] string transactionId)`

Comment: Great, how can I miss it!!

Comment: Is this attribute MVC6 only?

Comment: The header-name is Accept-Language, not Accepted-Language. Otherwise correct.

Comment: I found out that binding from headers currently only works with strings and collections of strings. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449885/binding-a-guid-parameter-in-asp-net-mvc-core/42471139#42471139)

Answer (score 0):

As [Daniel J.G.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31460183/571637) said, you can bind a Controller action parameter with `FromHeaderAttribute`.  But keep in mind that a Controller can access `Request.Headers` directly.  It might be nicer to leave off the Controller's language parameter and access the value as an enumeration via a property:

```
  public enum LanguageType
  {
     Unknown = -1,
     English,
     Spanish,
     German,
     Chinese
  }

  public LanguageType Language
  {
     get
     {
        string langStr = Request.Headers["Accept-Language"];
        switch (langStr.ToLower())
        {
           case "english":
              return LanguageType.English;
           case "spanish":
              return LanguageType.Spanish;
           case "german":
              return LanguageType.German;
           case "chinese":
              return LanguageType.Chinese;
           default:
              return LanguageType.Unknown;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: The header-name is Accept-Language, not Accepted-Language; Please don't copy-paste other people's mistakes without thinking.

Comment: @StefanSteiger thanks for your comment!  The header spelling is now corrected.