# How to filter an REST Result by sending custom request header parameter

Tags: endpoint, asp.net-core-webapi

i have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 WebApi Endpoint like this one:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It returns a collection of 'Sample'-Objects to the caller.

Now i do like to send within the Request Header a Custom Attribute like 'App-Type' which let the Endpoint know which App asks for Data. But what is to do that the endpoint fetches this Attribute so that i have it as variable within the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC5/6 Routing based on Http Header values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459580/asp-net-mvc5-6-routing-based-on-http-header-values)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a parameter in a controller action that reads from the headers, you should use `[FromHeader]` attribute, in your case it will be like `[FromHeader(Name="Accept-Language")]`. More information in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding