# HttpRequestMessage in .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm converting my project from the .NET Framework to .NET 6, I have a library for which there is an extension method for HttpRequestMessage, now in my action controller Request.IsSet is not working as it is pointing to the namespace "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core", earlier in the .Net framework it was pointing to "System.Web.Http", how can I point this to the "System.Web.Http" in .NET 6, I don't see any injectors in that controller.

```
public IActionResult GetMessage(string type = "", int timeout = 0, int visibilitytimeout = 0)
{
    if (Request.IsSet("contents"))     **// Cannot Compile this code**
    {
        //return the message contents only
        return StatusCode... ;
    }
}

// Below is the extension of HttpRequestMessage class
     
public static bool IsSet(this HttpRequestMessage request, string queryParamName)
{
     var val = request.GetQueryParamFirstValue(queryParamName) ?? "0";    
     return val.Equals("1") || val.Equals("true", 
               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your old extension method is just reading the query strings. You can use Request.Query.TryGetValue() to retrieve the parameter.

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. There's no System.Web.Http namespace any more, it was removed in .NET Core 3. What are you trying to do? Were you using ASP.NET Core 2 over .NET Framework perhaps? .NET Framework support was dropped in ASP.NET Core 3 and the architecture changed quite a lot.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how-to get IP Address client, and UserAgent **without System.Web.Http** ?

Comment: That's explained [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0). In all cases you start from HttpContext. Request headers are available through the Request property. The connection information through Connection

Comment: You can also use [FromHeaderAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromheaderattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to bind an action parameter to a header, [as this question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459580/asp-net-mvc5-6-routing-based-on-http-header-values): `[FromHeader(Name="Accept-Language")]string language`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to put the params directly into your Action.

So something like this:

```csharp
public IActionResult GetMessage(string type = "", int timeout = 0, int visibilitytimeout = 0, [FromQuery] string contents)
{
    if (contents is not null)
    {
        //return the message contents only
        return StatusCode... ;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to alter the extension method, you can do this:

```csharp
public static bool IsSet(this HttpRequest request, string queryParamName)
{
     return request.Query.ContainsKey(queryParamName);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change anything on the action method, I need the change on the extension

Comment: @Mysterious288 you can't *not* change almost everything when moving from .NET Framework to .NET Core. There's no `System.Web.Http` in any supported .NET Core version

Comment: How-to use it in NET 6 Web REST API ? In **MapPost** with _Minimal API_ ? For get IP Address client, and UserAgent

Comment: @Kiquenet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#special-types  

HttpContext has the IP, and Request Headers have the UA.  You can use the Extension method to check to see if the Key is there first.